# Google Machine Learning Crash Course MNIST example training diverge on local PC

Tags: machine-learning, mnist

I need help on the divergence behavior of MNIST code from [Google Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/)

The following code is copied from the MNIST example of Google Deep Learning Crash Course: [Programming Exercise: Classifying Handwritten Digits with Neural Networks](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/multi-class_classification_of_handwritten_digits.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=multiclass-colab&hl=en).

However, the training diverges on local PC (Windows or Linux)

[Divergence in Linux PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVL2.png)

The same code runs ok in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com)

[Convergence in Google Colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLLx.png)

Please advice how to debug.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import glob
import os

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format

mnist_dataframe = pd.read_csv(
#  "https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/mnist_train_small.csv",
  "mnist_train_small.csv",
  sep=",",
  header=None)

# Use just the first 10,000 records for training/validation.
mnist_dataframe = mnist_dataframe.head(10000)

mnist_dataframe = mnist_dataframe.reindex(np.random.permutation(mnist_dataframe.index))

def parse_labels_and_features(dataset):
  labels = dataset[0]

  features = dataset.loc[:,1:784]
  features = features / 255

  return labels, features

training_targets, training_examples = parse_labels_and_features(mnist_dataframe[:7500])

validation_targets, validation_examples = parse_labels_and_features(mnist_dataframe[7500:10000])


def construct_feature_columns():
  return set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=784)])

def create_training_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  def _input_fn(num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    idx = np.random.permutation(features.index)
    raw_features = {"pixels":features.reindex(idx)}
    raw_targets = np.array(labels[idx])

    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((raw_features,raw_targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(10000)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    feature_batch, label_batch = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return feature_batch, label_batch

  return _input_fn

def create_predict_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
  def _input_fn():
    raw_features = {"pixels": features.values}
    raw_targets = np.array(labels)

    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((raw_features, raw_targets)) # warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

    # Return the next batch of data.
    feature_batch, label_batch = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return feature_batch, label_batch

  return _input_fn

def train_nn_classification_model(
    learning_rate,
    steps,
    batch_size,
    hidden_units,
    training_examples,
    training_targets,
    validation_examples,
    validation_targets):

  periods = 3
  steps_per_period = steps / periods  

  # Create the input functions.
  predict_training_input_fn = create_predict_input_fn(
    training_examples, training_targets, batch_size)
  predict_validation_input_fn = create_predict_input_fn(
    validation_examples, validation_targets, batch_size)
  training_input_fn = create_training_input_fn(
    training_examples, training_targets, batch_size)

  # Create feature columns.
  feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column('pixels', shape=784)]

  # Create a DNNClassifier object.
  my_optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
  my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)
  classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      feature_columns=feature_columns,
      n_classes=10,
      hidden_units=hidden_units,
      optimizer=my_optimizer,
#      config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(keep_checkpoint_max=1),
      model_dir='./mdd'
  )

  # Train the model, but do so inside a loop so that we can periodically assess
  # loss metrics.
  print("Training model...")
  print("LogLoss error (on validation data):")
  training_errors = []
  validation_errors = []
  for period in range (0, periods):
    # Train the model, starting from the prior state.
    classifier.train(
        input_fn=training_input_fn,
        steps=steps_per_period
    )

    # Take a break and compute probabilities.
    training_predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn))
    training_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in training_predictions])
    training_pred_class_id = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in training_predictions])
    training_pred_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(training_pred_class_id,10)

    validation_predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn))
    validation_probabilities = np.array([item['probabilities'] for item in validation_predictions])    
    validation_pred_class_id = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in validation_predictions])
    validation_pred_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(validation_pred_class_id,10)    

    # Compute training and validation errors.
    training_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(training_targets, training_pred_one_hot)
    validation_log_loss = metrics.log_loss(validation_targets, validation_pred_one_hot)
    # Occasionally print the current loss.
    print("  period %02d : %0.2f" % (period, validation_log_loss))
    # Add the loss metrics from this period to our list.
    training_errors.append(training_log_loss)
    validation_errors.append(validation_log_loss)
  print("Model training finished.")
  # Remove event files to save disk space.
  #_ = map(os.remove, glob.glob(os.path.join(classifier.model_dir, 'events.out.tfevents*')))

  # Calculate final predictions (not probabilities, as above).
  final_predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
  final_predictions = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in final_predictions])

  accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(validation_targets, final_predictions)
  print("Final accuracy (on validation data): %0.2f" % accuracy)

  # Output a graph of loss metrics over periods.
  plt.ylabel("LogLoss")
  plt.xlabel("Periods")
  plt.title("LogLoss vs. Periods")
  plt.plot(training_errors, label="training")
  plt.plot(validation_errors, label="validation")
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()

  # Output a plot of the confusion matrix.
  cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(validation_targets, final_predictions)
  # Normalize the confusion matrix by row (i.e by the number of samples
  # in each class).
  cm_normalized = cm.astype("float") / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
  ax = sns.heatmap(cm_normalized, cmap="bone_r")
  ax.set_aspect(1)
  plt.title("Confusion matrix")
  plt.ylabel("True label")
  plt.xlabel("Predicted label")
  plt.show()

  return classifier

classifier = train_nn_classification_model(
    learning_rate=0.05,
    steps=300,
    batch_size=30,
    hidden_units=[100, 100],
    training_examples=training_examples,
    training_targets=training_targets,
    validation_examples=validation_examples,
    validation_targets=validation_targets)

mnist_test_dataframe = pd.read_csv(
#  "https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/mnist_test.csv",
  "mnist_test.csv",
  sep=",",
  header=None)

test_targets, test_examples = parse_labels_and_features(mnist_test_dataframe)
test_examples.describe()

predict_test_input_fn = create_predict_input_fn(
    test_examples, test_targets, batch_size=100)

test_predictions = classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_test_input_fn)
test_predictions = np.array([item['class_ids'][0] for item in test_predictions])

accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(test_targets, test_predictions)
print("Accuracy on test data: %0.2f" % accuracy)
```

[EDIT] It seems the problem lies in `np.random.permutation`. The following code can show the difference of the two platform. Does the PC version of Numpy/Pandas has issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]])

print(a)
print(list(a.index))

while 1:
    idx = np.random.permutation(a.index)
    if idx[0] == 1:
        break

print(a)
print(list(a.index))
print(idx)
```

Outputs from Google Colab

> ```
>    0  1
> 0  1  2
> 1  3  4
> [0, 1]
>    0  1
> 0  1  2
> 1  3  4
> [0, 1]
> [1 0]
> ```

Outputs from Linux PC:

> ```
>    0  1
> 0  1  2
> 1  3  4
> [0, 1]
>    0  1
> 1  1  2
> 0  3  4
> [0, 1]
> [1 0]
> ```

So it seems `np.random.permutation(a.index)` has different behaviors in two platforms. Is this a bug?

Comment: `np.random.permutation` and all other randomness based functions works based on a random number. The random number generated by a computer using any language or library is normally psuedo-random number. It will be different from machine to machine. ie the random number generated in colab may be 2018 on your machine it may be 1234 and so on. Also, if you haven't fixed the random seed the random number generated will change for different runs in the same machine

Answer (score 0):

`np.random.permutation` and all other randomness based functions works based on a random number.

The random number generated by a computer using any language or library is normally psuedo-random number. It will be different from machine to machine ie the random number generated in colab may be 2018 on your machine it may be 1234 and so on.

Also, if you haven't fixed the random seed the random number generated will change for different runs in the same machine.

This behavior might have induced problem for your model.

As a fix, you can try to fix the random seed and see what happens. But there is no gurantee that the random number generated in colab will match with that of your machine is the permuation.

Random seed can be fixed in numpy like this

```
seed = 1234
np.random.seed(seed)
```

If you run this every time you run the code, you can make sure that you can get the same set of random numbers.

For more details regarding randomness and getting re producible results see this excellent blog post [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/).